# I need Flash Support Code for Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, flash

I need Flash-supporting Xcode source code. Where can I find this?

Is there source code for a converter that takes .swf or .flv and changes it to .mp4 file format?

Some applications support Flash animation on iPhone, such as Puffin Web Browser. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand, but do you intend to write a flash application for iOS? if so, it will never work... [iOS does not support Flash](http://www.enterpriseirregulars.com/17744/top-10-reasons-why-steve-jobs-and-apple-reject-adobe-flash/)... and technically, [Flash is dying](http://blogs.adobe.com/flex/2011/11/your-questions-about-flex.html) ...

Answer (score 0):

as far as my knowledge iPhone doesn't support the flash